# LateX bibliography has a strange format: different paragraphs are created for the same reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I am writing my thesis in Latex and I have one problem with the Bibliography style.

I do not know why the same reference is split in more lines, even if I tried different coding styles. I post here what I wrote and I put the picture of what I obtain.

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,openbib]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left = 2.50cm, right = 2.50cm, top = 3.50cm, bottom=3.50cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{varioref} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{frontespizio}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{comment}


\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}







\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber, citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting = none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}



\addbibresource{biblio.bib}




\begin{document}


\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents\newpage



\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures\newpage


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables\newpage



\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{Introduction}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


\linespread{1}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\newpage


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You don't show how the offending bib entry is coded in `biblio.bib` so there's not enough information to determine why it's spreading out to so many lines.  Actually, all the entries are output to more lines than I would expect, so the bibliography style probably needs to be specified differently.

Comment: You are using the openbib  option in the class options. That makes every block into a paragraph.